# Can I build an electrostatic simulation of conductive objects using just the method of images?

Tags: simulation, electromagnetism

I wish to build a simulation of self-assembling wires. Think lots of ball bearings in a 20KV electric field and they form emergent structures.

If I use the method of images to figure out what the induced charges on various parts of these ball bearings due to all the other charges, is this enough to specify a general simulation that should computationally reproduce the experiment?

Are there any python, R, C#, or other libraries that already do this? Note, that I want to do it in 3D.

Comment: Will you look at arbitrons?

Comment: Method of images is not going to be any good here, you'll end up with infinite sets of images, and summing them up will be a pain. The method if images is good for  undergraduate electrostatics problems, with a point charge and a simple conducting surface; beyond that it is easier just to solve the Poisson equation.

Comment: Because you would need to sum an infinite number of reflections, this might not be very efficient. But there are several methods that generalize the method of images which might be suitable. See for example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_fundamental_solutions. In these methods, you put the image charges at fixed, ad hoc, locations, and compute their charges so that the boundary conditions are obeyed approximately.

Comment: Thanks - if I don't care about efficiency too much and just want approximate distribution of charges, then if I calculate just the images of the images is that enough of an approximation or could it be way off?

Comment: It could be way off. One way to check is to evaluate the error in the boundary conditions. Generally, for Laplace’s equation, the error is largest on the boundary, owing to the maximum principle. So you could add reflections until the error on the boundary, sampled on some set of points, is low enough for your application.